# #PLSQL_Trigger duplicate customer doesnt work

Tags: plsql

Homework requirement: create a trigger where account must belong to one and only one customer.

My code as shown below doesn't work. 
Error mesg: quoted string not properly terminated. Please help.

```
create or replace trigger dupcust
before insert or update on ACCOUNT
for each row
declare
    v_ctn NUMBER;
begin
    select count(account.cname) into v_ctn from account where A#=:new.A#;
    if v_ctn>0 then  
        raise_application_error (-20107, 'ACCT CAN ONLY BELONG TO ONE CUSTOMER');
    end if;
end;
```

Test code:

```
UPDATE ACCOUNT SET ACCOUNT.CNAME =’Cook’ WHERE ACCOUNT.A# = ‘1111’;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `A#` be the primary key of ACCOUNT? So it should be impossible to have more than one record per account number, so impossible for an Account to have more than one Customer.

Answer (score 2):

When I copied your query, it failed due to the quotes around the string cook and 1111.  You apparently used the wrong quote character, I corrected the quotes and when I run the query, the trigger generates a mutation error, the answer to that can can be found here:

[PLSQL Trigger Error. "is mutating, trigger/function may not see it" ORA-04091](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951730/plsql-trigger-error-is-mutating-trigger-function-may-not-see-it-ora-04091)

Basically you are reading from the table you are updating, that causes a mutation, you can't do that.

A compound trigger, if written correctly, would do the job, an example is here:

[Oracle trigger after insert or delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489951/oracle-trigger-after-insert-or-delete)

Comment: Hi Prescott, thank you so much for your comments and citations! I added pragma autonomous_transaction; in the declaration part and the trigger worked. Im wondering what this pragma autonomous_transaction does.

Comment: You can read about pragma autonomous_transaction here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm, basically it allows you to manipulate data inside the transactions without affecting data outside the transaction.

Comment: Autonomous transactions are not the right solution to this problem. The trigger code wouldn't see the newly inserted/updated rows in the calling session, so the "validation" will only succeed by accident.