# How to get new and old value of column in statement level trigger in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table  whose name is TestTable.

```
Create Table TestTable(ID number,Name nvarchar2(200))
```

I want to write a trigger. It's a statement level trigger. My question is:

- How to get new and old value of column in statement level trigger in oracle?

I can't use a row level trigger because I need to select row count from TestTable in trigger.

Comment: New and old values aren't available in a statement trigger. Perhaps if you edit your question and include the code for your trigger someone might be able to suggest a workaround. Thanks.

Comment: i need to get a new and old value of column. beacuse i update a table in trigger with update statement. When i update a table , i'll get a mutating error

Comment: Is this a [tag:mysql] or [tag:oracle] question ?

Comment: this is oracle question

Comment: Your best option is to use a compound trigger. [See this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489951/oracle-trigger-after-insert-or-delete). Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

As comments said you can't have access to `:new` and `:old` on statement level. How can you define row values if trigger that see whole statement?

Please use `compound trigger` ([Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005) and [Example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/compound-triggers-in-oracle-11g-tutorial-example/)). There you can write section that is statement level and another one `for each row`. Count you'll get in `statement` level and access to `:old` and `:new` you'll have on `for each row section`

Comment: i know it  cant get old and new value in row level trigget. okay. but how to update more row of table in trigger ? i can update only one row in row level trigger. and i cant get  old and new value in statement level trigger. But how to update rows in trigger ? for example i have a TestTable. and i want to update row which is name like '%El%' .Dou you understood me ?

Comment: @ElvinHabibov You can gather ids of rows you want to update in `for each row` and then process whole update inn `statement` section. I've attached you some links. If you need more help please describe your problem, what data do you have, what you need to do and so on

Comment: for example. 
ID | NAME 
1      Elvin