# how to use count in trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 columns in 2 different tables: `col1` ->`table1` and `col2` -> `table2` . One of them contains values that are not UNIQUE and the other one stores the times each values of `table1` appeared. I need to create a trigger that will re-calculate `col2` on update of `col1`. I read somewhere that you can not query the updating table in trigger, then how can i do this? Can anyone help me?

```
 table1:    pri_key     col1
             1           2
             2           2
             3           2
             4           3  
table2:     pri_key(col1)    col2
             1                0
             2                3
             3                1 
             4                0
```

p/s:sorry for the bad english

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: It would usually be better and easier to have a [materialised] view that calculates the count, rather than trying to maintain a value manually like that.

Comment: In fact you can, you mean table mutating when say that can't read from updatable table, but you can use compound trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a compound trigger.  An example can be found here:

[Oracle trigger after insert or delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489951/oracle-trigger-after-insert-or-delete)