# Cannot to create trigger properly

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Oracle apex, PL_Sql. 
This is my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NoMoreThanOneHorse
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Jockey_ID
    ON Horses
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    NumOfHorsesForJockey NUMBER(4);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO NumOfHorsesForJockey FROM Horses
        WHERE Jockey_ID = :NEW.Jockey_ID AND Horse_ID <> :NEW.Horse_ID;
    IF NumOfHorsesForJockey > 0
        THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20445, 'Нельзя закрепить за лошадью уже занятого жокея!');
        END IF;
END NoMoreThanOneHorse;
```

but every time i try to create it i have this error :ORA-24344: success with compilation error ORA-06512. I suppose it's because bad syntax

Comment: Add SHOW ERRORS; at the end of your pl/sql block. It will show the exact error on the result page.

Comment: @Novice_Techie, idk why but it doesn't show me any errors, only one i described before

Comment: Try using END; instead of END NoMoreThanOneHorse; in the last line.

Comment: @Novice_Techie, the same error :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the compile-time error might be - it compiles fine for me. But at run-time you'll probably get an `ORA-04091 Table HORSES is mutating, trigger cannot see it" error. You can't fetch from HORSES in a ROW trigger which is defined on the HORSES table.

What you need to do is to change this to an AFTER STATEMENT trigger, which you do by leaving off the `FOR EACH ROW` in the trigger definition, and changing the trigger point from BEFORE to AFTER. The problem is that in a statement trigger you don't have access to the `:NEW` or `:OLD` data, but you don't really need it. A statement trigger is invoked only once for each statement which is executed. So your trigger should look something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NoMoreThanOneHorse
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF Jockey_ID
    ON Horses
DECLARE
    nMaxHorses  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(HORSE_COUNT)
      INTO nMaxHorses
      FROM (SELECT JOCKEY_ID, COUNT(*) AS HORSE_COUNT
              FROM Horses
              GROUP BY Jockey_ID);

    IF nMaxHorses > 1 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20445, 'Нельзя закрепить за лошадью уже занятого жокея!');
    END IF;
END NoMoreThanOneHorse;
```

You really don't care which jockey has been assigned too many horses, only that there is a jockey who's been put on more than one horse.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8260dab3eff0c31c61470f7a68e8c78c)

Comment: If this is a real question rather than a homework assignment, unless the table is really small and seldom inserted into, doing a full scan of the table and grouping the data every time you insert a new row is going to be rather slow (and expensive).  If you want to go with a trigger, you'd want a row-level trigger that puts the changed rows in a collection and uses that collection to narrow down the query the statement-level trigger runs.

Comment: @JustinCave - although OP *could* be writing software for a race track I strongly suspect this is a homework assignment, which is why I suggested a statement trigger. [I agree that in the real world a compound trigger would be a better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29491264/213136).

Comment: @BobJarvisReinstateMonica - Agreed.  Just pointing it out for any future readers that might have a real system.

Comment: @BobJarvisReinstateMonica - Let me enjoy my fantasy world, OK?